# Simple guide to Game Center Integration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gamekit

Could anyone point me in the direction of an idiots guide to integrating Game Center into an iPhone app ? Please do not refer me to any Apple documentation as it's about as useful as a pork chop at a barmitzvah.

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: Of their flesh shall ye not eat, and their carcase shall ye not touch; they are unclean to you.

Comment: I just read through the "Game Kit Programming Guide" on Apple's doc website and I have a very clear understanding of how to integrate it into my apps.  What's your confusion, perhaps I can help?

Comment: Go through this link . It may help you.http://vivianaranha.com/integrating-apple-gamecenter-to-your-application/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you can't read Apple Fantastic documentation, maybe you should give OpenFeint a go

a lot of games out there uses it and you can find a "simple guide" on [Pocket Worx website](http://pocketworx.com/?p=80)

Answer (score 1):

How about the WWDC video? Session 408 is pretty introductory.

Answer (score 1):

If your games already have OpenFeint as you say, OF has a built-in GameCenter integration. All you need to do is set a bool and provide a .plist containing associations between your OF Achievement IDs and your GC Achievement IDs. The process is documented on their developer support site.